# UIView: how to set property before initWithFrame is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, initialization

I have some `MyView` as a subclass of `UIView` with following methods:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

@end

@implementation

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self = [self init];
    self.image = image;

    return self;
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //here I want to access my image property
    }
}

@end
```

Out of this class I initialize object like that:

```
[[MyView alloc] initWithImage: someimage];
```

`initWithFrame:` is required, `initWithImage:` is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a property on the object before you call the initialiser because until that has been called the object does not exist. If the initialiser needs access to a property, you will need to supply it as a parameter (since it is a *requirement* for successful creation of your object).

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

takes a `CGRect` parameter because the purpose of this method is to create an instance with a predefined frame; it adds functionality to the default `NSObject`'s `- (instancetype) init`, so is supplied with the `frame` parameter to work with.

A `UIView` needs a frame so it can be layed out on screen and rendered (amongst other things). At some point in the implementation it will perform a call to the default `[super init]` method and then access `self` to work with the frame it has been handed. It *builds* on an existing class.

You are building on the `UIView` class in that you want to to be able to initialise it with a `UIImage`.  You can either opt to provide a default frame for your subclass:

```
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)]) {
        self.image = image;
    }
}
```

Or provide a more 'useful' default value (Like [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/initWithImage:) would do) and take the image dimensions as the default frame:

> Initializing a UIImageView Object
>
> `- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image`
>
> **Discussion**
> This method adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the specified image. It also disables user interactions for the image view by default.

With an initialiser like:

```
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)]) {
        self.image = image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you init your "MyView" with initWithImage, I doubt it shall call initWithFrame. What I recomend you is to use

```
   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame :(UIImage *)image
```

or better

```
   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame image:(UIImage *)image.
```

So you can pass image in the same method call.  Make sure you add

```
   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame image:(UIImage *)image;
```

also in your .h file.